# Division of climate variable from to nc files

Tags: ubuntu, netcdf, cdo-climate

I would like to divide a given variable `prob` from a file of future climate `AK2100.nc` with the same variable from the file of contemporary time `AK.nc`.
I tried this

```
cdo div AK2100.nc AK.nc division-AK2100.nc
```

But it divided all the three variables, including the `lat` and `lon`. How can I specifically target the variable of interest `prob` and only divide these two similar variables but keep the spatial aspect?

Comment: that's bizarre, it shouldn't do that if the lat and lon are defined as dimensions and the file follows CF conventions... any chance we can see the file, perhaps provide a link?

Comment: @AdrianTompkins, I am not sure how I could share the file.
The `lat` and `lon` are defined as dimensions, and the `probability` defined as a variable. But, once executed I get that it has `processed 2 variables over 2 timesteps`

Comment: aha! that just means 1 variable from the first file and 1 from the second! ;-) if you look at the output with ncview it will be fine and on the same grid.

Comment: Sounds about right @AdrianTompkins. I can't imagine the code in CDO would go that wrong that it says it's processing 2 variables when it's processing 3

Comment: @thomas, did you check the output from the standard CDO command you posted with ncview?  I presume it was fine, can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cdo  -div -selname,prob AK2100.nc AK.nc division-AK2100.nc
```

Comment: I'm sorry? Adding `-selname,prob` applies targets the division to the variable prob as the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

Try [ncbo](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#xmp_ncbo)

```
ncbo -v prob -y divide AK2100.nc AK.nc out.nc
```